# Can anyone tell me the name of this laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform

I need to apply this rule to solve a Laplace transform:

$\mathcal{L(\frac{f(t)}{t})}=\int_s^\infty F(u) du$

I've been given a table on laplace transform "rules" but I don't know how to use this one. My textbook doesn't even mention it. What's its name? How do I use it? And if possible, how do I prove it?

Thanks.

Edit: I have to solve the laplace transform of $\frac{-cos(5t)+cos(8t)}{t}$ I guess we can simplify my problem by just saying I have to solve the laplace transform of $\frac{-cos(5t)}{t}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems

Rule "Frequency integration", 7th row in the table. To answer the "how do I use it?", it would be helpful if you'd post your actual problem.

---

Applying the rule to your problem yields

$$f(t) = -\cos(5t) \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ F(\tilde{s}) = -\frac{\tilde{s}}{\tilde{s}^2+5^2}$$

Now the Laplace transform in question is

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{-cos(5t)}{t}\right\} = -\int_s^\infty \frac{\tilde{s}}{\tilde{s}^2+5^2} d\tilde{s}$$

and further

$$-\frac{1}{2}\int_s^\infty \frac{2\tilde{s}}{\tilde{s}^2+5^2} d\tilde{s} 
= -\frac{1}{2}\left.\log(\tilde{s}^2+5^2)\right|_{\tilde{s}=s}^{\tilde{s}=\infty} 
= \left.\log\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tilde{s}^2+5^2}}\right|_{\tilde{s}=s}^{\tilde{s}=\infty}$$
$$= \log\frac{1}{\sqrt{\infty^2+5^2}} + \log\sqrt{s^2+5^2} = \log(0) + \log\sqrt{s^2+5^2}$$

and the solution is

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{-\cos(5t)}{t}\right\} = \log(0) + \log\sqrt{s^2+5^2}$$

The $\log(0) = -\infty$ is the result of only considering half of the problem. For the full problem see below.

---

Applied on the full question, this is

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{-\cos(5t)+\cos(8t)}{t}\right\} = \log\sqrt{s^2+5^2} - \log\sqrt{s^2+8^2} = \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{s^2+5^2}{s^2+8^2}\right)$$

but I think one has to perform the limit (won't write it out)

$$\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\int_s^u F(\tilde{s}) d\tilde{s}$$

to reliably argue

$$\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{2} \log\left(\frac{u^2+8^2}{u^2+5^2}\right) = \log(1) = 0$$

Comment: Sorry, but all I see there is the same formula I have. I have no idea what substitution to make, or why it works. If I click on the link on "frequency integration" i'm directed to a very basic article on what frequency is.

Comment: Well, you asked for the name and I delivered ;) For the question about the usage, you best post your actual problem.

Comment: Ok, I posted my actual problem. Thanks.

Comment: I added what I got, but it's no solution, sorry.

Comment: I solved it, I hope everything is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if there's any proof out there for this technique?

Comment: This is wrong. You can not transform one cosine term at a time, since each of them diverges. Only both term combined gives a convergent answer. Therefore set $f(t)=\cos(8t)-\cos(5t)$ then apply the formula.

Comment: I edited quite a few things. The fishy solution makes me believe your words Hansen. What do mean with "both term"? EDIT: Ah I see what you mean! I won't start over though, I am done hehe.

Comment: If you consider my entire problem, the term $ln\infty$ is cancelled and you get the solution $1/2 ln(\frac{s^2+25}{s^2+64})$

Comment: Yeah David, I figured it's not a big step and edited the full answer. I hope it's entirely correct and solved now.